# Cannot enable TP-LINK W822N on new Windows10 installation

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, router, drivers

I just reinstalled Windows 10 64 bit after formatting my hard disk, and I'm trying to connect my TP-Link W822N-V2 wireless adapter. The TP-Link utility tool won't work and does not enable any option to be set. Also the tool's tooltip says disabled in the minitray. 
The steps I tried:

  1. The driver and utility tools I downloaded from: http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-WN822N_V2.html#Utility doesn't quite work. The wireless adapter is recognized and the green light on it turns on however the utility tool won't scan for networks.

  2. Right Click enable wireless in networks and sharing center but doesn't do anything.

  3. Uninstall the driver I just installed.

  4. I tried going through the Windows 10 Driver store uninstalling the drivers I installed from TP-Link by doing Update Driver -> Browse my computer... -> Let me pick from a list of device drivers from my computer -> Network Adapters -> TP-LINK Technologies Co. -> TP-LINK 300MBPS Wireless High Powered USB Adapter.

Is there a step or anything else I can try?

Comment: What does your device status show as under Device Manager? `Win` + `X` -> `Device Manager`. Should be under network adapters, can you tell us what it says in the box?

Comment: After step 1 and step 4 the device status was good (no warning sign over device icon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the drivers I downloaded for 822N-V2 included driver files other then Windows7-64 bit. I had to uninstall the driver and clear the files from my computer and when reinstalling manually select the folder with Windows7-64 bit drivers. There is no Windows 10 drivers for TP-Link and the site only says that its coming soon. After installing the right driver I was able to connect setup my wireless settings.